# How to add manifest permission QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#all-apps) says to add permission to the manifest in order to get all installed applications on the device starting from Android 11 and above, I added but underlines in red and writes

**A declaration should generally be used instead of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES; see https://g.co/dev/packagevisibility for details**

What am I doing wrong?

```
<manifest ...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
 ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is because it is a `Restricted Permissions`, Only specific applications (i.e. OEM, system, preinstalled apps in ROM) can use this kind of permission.

Comment: When you are working on Android Studio, same restrictions will be applied to your application, assuming that you are submitting the app to Google Play Store by default. So this is the reason of the red lines appeared.

Comment: REF: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-query-all-packages-permission

`If your app does not meet the requirements for acceptable use below, you must remove it from your app's manifest in order to comply with Play policy. `

So the keyword here is whether your app requires to comply with Play policy (i.e. submitting to Google Play Store). Though even you are a private app developer, you shall be-aware that in future Android world this permission may further restrict to system app only